# JS form can't get it to submit

Tags: javascript

After validating my form with javascript I can not get it to submit to the server

```
myForm.addEventListener("submit", validation);
  function validation(e) {
  let data = {};
  e.preventDefault();
  errors.forEach(function(item) {
 item.classList.add("cart__hide");
   });
```

at the end of the validation I have the following code

```
    if (!error) {
      myForm.submit();
     }
```

I also tried

```
     if (error = false) {
     myForm.submit();
      }

     if ((error == false)) {
     myForm.submit();
        }
```

when I console log error I am getting all `false` so the form should submit.
I am getting the following console log error

> TypeError: myForm.submit is not a function

I did this same validation on an html page and it worked fine.  Now I am trying to get it to work on a PHP page and it will not submit. 
I am not sure why the `myForm.submit()` is causing the error. 
Thanks
Jon

Comment: can you share the html side of things. Is `myForm` definitely set to the right variable? e.g `<form id="myForm"></form>` and then `let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');` 

Sounds simple but could be a copy paste error I guess but you've changed IDs

Comment: Ankur Mishra gave me the solution but thanks much for your willingness to help out a javascript rookie

Answer (score 2):

Remove `e.preventDefault();` from your code and put it in your validation function like this:

```
if (error) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to only call `Event#preventDefault` when there is an error.

```js
myForm.addEventListener("submit", validation);

function validation(e) {
  var error = !form.checkValidity(); // replace this with the actual validation
  if (error) e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Jon I'm glad I could help. If the answer, solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the check to left of it.